# WooCommerce REST API: products endpoint returns empty array

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm calling the following endpoint: `wp-json/wc/v3/products` with GET. But it returns an empty array. I know I am authorized because it gives a different message when there is an authentication error. Could this be a bug in WooCommerce? What headers should I be sending?

Comment: Please provide the request code completely by masking the CS and CK

Comment: @mujuonly I used Postman to send the request. I didn't pass any GET parameters.

Comment: http://local.mujuonly.wp/index.php/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_6f553d1898b442f1b066372536793551fd919b33&consumer_secret=cs_dfec7cf95b376627d3bd97219eecab3020038a7f - Accessing the URL like this returns the products

Comment: @mujuonly doesn't work for me :/

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

NO, this is not a bug in WooCommerce.
You need to use "/" at end of End point like wp-json/wc/v3/products/